# Can I perform a nonstop voluntary fast for a certain time?

Tags: sawm

I'd like to know that if I can keep nonstop voluntary fasts for a certain time for any good purpose. Can anyone please explain in detail?

Comment: yes, you can do that, and its good also.

Comment: Hello bro, thanks,... if you dont mind, can you please share any reference regarding to this, whenever you get time? I didnt find any, so was eagerly looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can fast voluntarily because the Prophet s.a.w fasted on Mondays and Thursdays. So you can do the same as well. Or sometimes when people feel that their sexual desires have risen, then they fast because it lowers them. The prophet s.a.w said for those who cannot marry to keep a fast.  This is just part of the hadith.

Comment: My question is if I can keep fasting everyday, not in alternative days.